# Bugzilla error while searching with bug no's

Tags: bugzilla

I have bugzilla3.2 running on a ubuntu server. I would login from the webconsole (http://ip/bugzilla3.2/) and update the bugs. When I enter the bug number eg:181, I'm getting following error on the browser

> undef error - DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Got error 28 from storage engine [for Statement "SELECT DISTINCT groups.id, name, description, CASE WHEN bug_group_map.group_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, CASE WHEN groups.id IN(13,4,1,10,11,6,2,8,12,5,3,7,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, isactive, membercontrol, othercontrol FROM groups LEFT JOIN bug_group_map ON bug_group_map.group_id = groups.id AND bug_id = ? LEFT JOIN group_control_map ON group_control_map.group_id = groups.id AND group_control_map.product_id = ? WHERE isbuggroup = 1 ORDER BY description" with ParamValues: 0='181', 1='4'] at Bugzilla/Bug.pm line 2575 Bugzilla::Bug::groups('Bugzilla::Bug=HASH(0x2fc5538)') called at template/en/default/bug/edit.html.tmpl line 691 eval {...} called at template/en/default/bug/edit.html.tmpl line 691 eval {...} called at template/en/default/bug/edit.html.tmpl line 784 Template::Provider::**ANON**('Template::Context=HASH(0x2e0c068)') called at lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Template/Context.pm line 348 eval {...} called at lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Template/Context.pm line 321 Template::Context::process('Template::Context=HASH(0x2e0c068)', 'section_restrict_visibility') called at template/en/default/bug/edit.html.tmpl line 212 eval {...} called at template/en/default/bug/edit.html.tmpl line 18 Template::Provider::**ANON**('Template::Context=HASH(0x2e0c068)') called at lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Template/Document.pm line 151 eval {...} called at lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Template/Document.pm line 149 Template::Document::process('Template::Document=HASH(0x3359c48)', 'Template::Context=HASH(0x2e0c068)') called at lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Template/Context.pm line 351 eval {...} called at lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Template/Context.pm line 321 Template::Context::process('Template::Context=HASH(0x2e0c068)', 'bug/edit.html.tmpl') called at template/en/default/bug/show.html.tmpl line 65 eval {...} called at template/en/default/bug/show.html.tmpl line 16 Template::Provider::**ANON**('Template::Context=HASH(0x2e0c068)') called at lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Template/Document.pm line 151 eval {...} called at lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Template/Document.pm line 149 Template::Document::process('Template::Document=HASH(0x2fb2680)', 'Template::Context=HASH(0x2e0c068)') called at lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Template/Context.pm line 351 eval {...} called at lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Template/Context.pm line 321 Template::Context::process('Template::Context=HASH(0x2e0c068)', 'Template::Document=HASH(0x2fb2680)') called at lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Template/Service.pm line 94 eval {...} called at lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Template/Service.pm line 91 Template::Service::process('Template::Service=HASH(0x2e0bb40)', 'bug/show.html.tmpl', 'HASH(0x1929fb8)') called at lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Template.pm line 66 Template::process('Bugzilla::Template=HASH(0x2d83848)', 'bug/show.html.tmpl', 'HASH(0x1929fb8)') called at /var/www/bugzilla-3.2/show_bug.cgi line 141

Need help...

I could find the following error while trying to restart mysql

> - Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                 [ OK ]
> - /etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Error 38` means the same error that you're seeing when you try to start mysql -- your disk is probably full.

use `df -h` to check the amount of free space.